# Vue-Mapbox zoom events

Tags: vue.js, zooming, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

i was using `vue-mapbox` and wanted to get an event every time theres a zoom change, is that possible with `vue-mapbox`? or if i can use any other alternative options?

or as an alternative if theres a click event for the `<MglNavigationControl />` component which controls the zoom?

it tried adding `@click` on the `<MglNavigationControl @click="click" />` but it doesnt work

```
method : {
click(){
 alert('zoom button clicked')
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there's no event or action exposed in `vue-mapbox` for working with zoom events. You've to work around this by doing something like this:

```
<VueMapbox
  mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
  accessToken="<token>"
  @load="onMapLoad"
/>
```

```
 methods: {
    onMapLoad({ map }) {
      map.on("zoomend", e => {
        alert('Zoom end: ' + e.target.getZoom());
      });
    }
  }
```